# Display objects based on attribute

Tags: python, django

This is very simple. I have a database of objects with pin attributes.

**use case**

- user inputs 4-digit pin
- displays objects with matching pin number

What is the simplest way to accomplish this in django?

index.html

```
<form action="/polls/" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %} 
    <p>
        <label for="pin">Enter group pin:</label> 
        <input id="pin" type="text" name="pin" maxlength="4" /> 
        <input type="submit" value="View Polls" />
    </p>
</form>
```

Currently it's hard coded in

```
{% for poll in latest_poll_list %}
    {% if poll.pin == "1234" %}
        <ul class="poll-list">
            <li><a href="/polls/{{ poll.id }}/">{{ poll.question }}</a> - {{poll.pin}}</li>
        </ul>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty new to django so there may be a better solution, but I'll give it a try.
In your view you can do something like this. Considering your code I assume you have a class 
`Poll`

```
poll = Poll.objects.filter(pin=request.POST['pin'])
```